# AngularJS/Grunt encoding issue

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, encoding, gruntjs

I'm using `grunt serve` to serve my angular app, but I've got an encoding issue... I have a fake json which I read locally using `$http` service, this json contains strings with "special" characters (like "è", "ì"...) that are not rendered properly. In my html page I defined:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

And I also configured explicitly angular to require that encoding:

```
config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
}]);
```

but the characters are still "broken"... what should I do? Is perhaps this issue something related to Grunt?

Comment: Does your fake JSON comes from a file? Maybe that file is not properly encoded.

Comment: yes... fixed... I saved the file using "save with encoding" option in sublime and now it works properly... please post your comment as a response and I will mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your fake JSON comes from a file? Maybe that file is not properly encoded.